# Removing leading zeros from a ggplot2 figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, leading-zero

I am trying to use ggplot to generate a heatmap of a correlation matrix without including leading zeros in the data.

Consider this example from LifeCycleSavings in the "datasets" package:

```
       pop75    dpi   ddpi
sr     0.317  0.220  0.305
pop15 -0.908 -0.756 -0.048
```

I can plot a [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz7Eg.png) like so:

```
library(reshape2)
melted_cors <- melt(cors)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melted_cors, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(Var2, Var1, label = value), color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red",
                       midpoint = 0, limit = c(0,1), space = "Lab", 
                       name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(title = element_blank(), legend.position="none") +
  coord_fixed()
```

Is there any way to strip the leading zeroes from this output?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by leading zeros? Do you want to hide terms with zero correlation? Do you want to multiply all of the correlations by 10 to remove the zero before the decimal point?

Comment: not reproducible. what is `cors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns and rows may be reversed. Using gsub works but is not very elegant.

```
cors <- read.table(text=
"label  pop75    dpi   ddpi
sr     0.317  0.220  0.305
pop15 -0.908 -0.756 -0.048", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
melted_cors <- melt(cors)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melted_cors, aes(label, variable, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label, variable, label = gsub("0\\.", "\\.", value)), color = "black", size = 4) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red",
                       midpoint = 0, limit = c(0,1), space = "Lab", 
                       name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(title = element_blank(), legend.position="none") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Followup up question: is it possible to display the same number of digits after the decimal across all cells (e.g., .03, .30, .00 instead of .03, .3, and 0)?

Comment: Yes. With geom_text - the value is literally any string so you could do any manipulations. the function `sprintf("%.2f", 3.141)` will round to 2 decimal places. so something like `gsub("0\\.", "\\.",  (sprintf("%.2f, value))`